# Using the each function within getJSON returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I'm using jQuery's getJSON method to retrive and parse a simple JSON file, but when I output the values onto my page it's displaying as `undefined`

```
$.getJSON( 'js/example.json', function ( data ) {

    var output = '';

    $.each( data.exercises, function ( index, exercise ) {
        output += '<li>' + exercise.work.weight + ' x ' + exercise.work.reps  + '</li>';
    });

    $( '#example' ).html( output );

});
```

`example.json`

```
{

    "exercises" : [

        {
            "name" : "Squats",
            "work" : [
                {
                    "weight" : 135,
                    "reps" : 5
                },
                {
                    "weight" : 225,
                    "reps" : 5
                },
                {
                    "weight" : 315,
                    "reps" : 5
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "name" : "Bench",
            "work" : [
                {
                    "weight" : 135,
                    "reps" : 5
                },
                {
                    "weight" : 225,
                    "reps" : 5
                },
                {
                    "weight" : 315,
                    "reps" : 5
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "name" : "Rows",
            "work" : [
                {
                    "weight" : 135,
                    "reps" : 5
                },
                {
                    "weight" : 225,
                    "reps" : 5
                },
                {
                    "weight" : 315,
                    "reps" : 5
                }
            ]

        }

    ]


}
```

I think the error might lie within my each function, but I haven't been able to identify it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: If you console.log output within your each statement, does it provide the outcome you're looking for?

Comment: `exercise.work` is an array. You'll need to iterate over it, or target an individual item.

Comment: Given that each `exercise` has multiple `work.weight` values, which one did you expect to receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exercise work is an array, need another loop

```
$.each( data.exercises, function ( index, exercise ) {
    $.each(exercise.work, function (index, work) {
         console.log(work);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but the looped data repeats itself 3 times.

Comment: well, you have 3 items in each exercise.work, if you want just first one change loop to exercise.work[0]

Comment: Sorry, there's no repeating. Just a bug on my side.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
output += '<li>' + exercise.work.weight + ' x ' + exercise.work.reps  + '</li>';
```

assumes your JSON looks like:

```
"exercises" : [
  {
    "name" : "Squats",
    "work" : 
      {
        "weight" : 135,
        "reps" : 5
      }
  },
```

When in fact `work` is an array in each case.

You want something like:

```
$.each( data.exercises, function ( index, exercise ) {

   $.each( exercise.work, function( index, workout ) { 
      output += '<li>' + workout.weight + ' x ' + workout.reps  + '</li>';
   });

});
```